# SQL error when deleting database rows. Android CAB and listview

Tags: android, sql, listview, delete-row

My uses a SimpleCursor adapter to populate a listview in the main activity. I'm not trying to use a contextual action bar (CAB) to delete items from the list and database. My main questions are:

1.Is this the correct approach.
2.What is wrong with my deleteRecord method.

My error is:

> SQLiteException: near "LIKE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM clutchesTable WHERE _id LIKE

CAB button click code:

```
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_discard:
                    //TO DO call action code here
                    Log.i(TAG, "delete button clicked " + 5);

                    Integer position = ListView.getCheckedItemPosition();

                    cursor.moveToPosition(position);

                   Integer recordID =cursor.getInt(0);
                   DbHelper.deleteRecord(recordID);



                    mode.finish(); // Action picked, so close the CAB
                    Log.i(TAG, "onActionItemClicked method end" + 6);
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
```

DbHelper delete method:

```
public void deleteRecord(Integer recordID) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // Define 'where' part of query.
    String whereClause = ClutchDBContract.clutches._ID + " LIKE ";
    // Specify arguments in placeholder order.
    String[] whereArgs = { String.valueOf(recordID) };


    db.delete("clutchesTable",whereClause,whereArgs);
}
```

On long press code to open CAB.

```
        clutchList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            // Called when the user long-clicks on clutchList
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (mActionMode != null) {
                    return false;
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "onLongClick even triggered, CAB not open");
                clutchList.setItemChecked(position, true);
                // Start the CAB using the ActionMode.Callback defined above
                mActionMode = getActivity().startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
                Log.i(TAG, "Call to CAB completed");
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: is it `deleteRecord` or `deleteClutch`?

Comment: `DELETE FROM clutchesTable WHERE _id LIKE` _id is of type **integer**. LIKE wants a string to compare. If you want to delete a range of ids, then use something like `WHERE _id BETWEEN 12 and 16` (to say some numbers)

Comment: deleteRecord. Doesn't `String.valueof` cast it to a string? I know it's being stored in my string array.

Comment: Well **LIKE doesn't want an integer**. It's used to match strings, not numbers (`LIKE '%had a little%'` matches `'Mary had a little lamb'` as well as `'Paul had a little dog'`, for instance). **_id is a numeric field**, not a string field.

Comment: oh ok. I'm using the wrong operator then. I figured `=` would be more appropriate. But now I'm getting a similar error.  `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM clutchesTable WHERE _id =
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)`